# Some youtube video in iFrame is not working only in Android

Tags: android, iframe, youtube

We have implemented YouTube videos in iFrame on three platforms (Android, iOS, and web (Angular)). However, we are experiencing an issue where some videos are unavailable on the Android Platform. We have looked for solutions, but none have been found. The same video is working on iOS and Angular platforms.

Below are three iFrames from Android, which are the same as iOS and Angular. See the attached Android, iOS, and web screenshots.

**The below video is unavailable on Android:**

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DwenbrW2Ljs" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**The below videos are working fine:**

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1wntBImcNqU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KS_letyBOZ8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Android (See 1st video preview)**

[image]

**iOS (See 1st video preview)**

[image]

**WEB (See 1st video preview)**

[image]

Below is my Android code for reference:

```
val webView = WebView(root.context)
webView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 230.dpToPx())
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
webView.loadData(iFrame, “text/html”, “utf-8")
linearYoutube.addView(webView)
```